# Jest/TypeORM purge database after all tests

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, typeorm

I would like to delete all entries into my database after or before all jest tests.

Here is my setup.js:

```
import { getConnection, getConnectionManager } from "typeorm"

beforeAll(async () => {
    const connectionManager = getConnectionManager()
    const connection = connectionManager.create({
        "type": "postgres",
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 54320,
        "username": "test",
        "password": "test",
        "database": "test",
        "entities": ["../src/entities/*.ts"],
        "logging": false,
        "synchronize": true
    })
    await connection.connect()
})

afterAll(async () => {
    await getConnection().close()
})
```

I read on the typeorm documentation that the "synchronize" option would override the old tables with new one which are empty but it doesn't seems to work.

Here is the test I made:

```
describe('POST /create', () => {
    it('Create a user', async () => {
        const user: IStringTMap<string> = {
            firstName: 'John',
            lastName: 'Doe',
            email: 'john.doe@test.com',
            password: 'test123!',
        }

        const res: Response = await request(app)
            .post('/create')
            .send(user)
            .expect(200)

        expect(res.type).toEqual('application/json')
        expect(res.body.email).toBe('john.doe@test.com')
        expect(res.body.password).toBe(undefined)
    })
})
```

First `yarn test` works but the next one doesn't (email already exists)

Any idea?

Answer (score 19):

Maybe a little late but was searching for this as well, this is what I came up with.

This will only delete the content inside the entities, not the entities itself.

```
afterEach(async () => {

    // Fetch all the entities
    const entities = getConnection().entityMetadatas;

    for (const entity of entities) {
        const repository = getConnection().getRepository(entity.name); // Get repository
        await repository.clear(); // Clear each entity table's content
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT:** If you're using **foreign keys**, make sure to add the `{onDelete: "CASCADE"}` property to your columns in order to delete all the records correctly.

More information about that can be found here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1460#issuecomment-366982161

Comment: You won't be able to clear an entity that is dependent upon another entity with this code.

Comment: True, I'm not using explicit foreign keys in my database. This is because I've a microservice architecture.

Comment: Pushed an edit to make this work with foreign keys.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple and efficient way to fully clean a DB with typeorm, in creating a dedicated TestService which TRUNCATE all entities in one command:

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Connection } from "typeorm";

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  constructor(@Inject("Connection") public connection: Connection) {}

  public async cleanDatabase(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const entities = this.connection.entityMetadatas;
      const tableNames = entities.map((entity) => `"${entity.tableName}"`).join(", ");
      
      await this.connection.query(`TRUNCATE ${tableNames} CASCADE;`);
      console.log("[TEST DATABASE]: Clean");
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`ERROR: Cleaning test database: ${error}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can call this function in your testing files:

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
  await testService.cleanDatabase();
});
```

Comment: Cool! But in our case we need to reset the `id` so we use `await dataSource.manager.query(`TRUNCATE TABLE ${tableNames} RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;`);`

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I do not have enough reputation to respond to Michiel's comment but,

if you are using a postgreSQL database and your table have foreign key constraints your code may not work because according to the [postgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-truncate-table/#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20TRUNCATE%20TABLE%20statement%20to%20delete%20all%20data%20from,TRUNCATE%20and%20AFTER%20TRUNCATE%20triggers.) TRUNCATE does not fire an ON DELETE trigger

> The TRUNCATE TABLE does not fire ON DELETE trigger. Instead, it fires the BEFORE TRUNCATE and AFTER TRUNCATE triggers.

So you will probably have to use the [EntityManager](https://typeorm.io/entity-manager-api) to make an SQL query like this:

```js
entityManager.query('TRUNCATE TABLE table_name CASCADE;')
```

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31934612)

Answer (score 3):

you can setup a new database in your e2e test file with a separate name and set the `dropSchema: true` option when you import the typeorm module. you can import the typeorm module int he imports the same way you do in AppModule

Answer (score 2):

Note: examples with `getConnection` is deprecated now.
A new approach could be:

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { databaseConfig } from '../src/config/database'; // TypeORM configuration

export const clearDatabase = async () => {
  const appDataSource = new DataSource(databaseConfig);
  const entities = appDataSource.entityMetadatas;

  for await (const entity of entities) {
    const repository = appDataSource.getRepository(entity.name);

    await repository.query(
      `TRUNCATE ${entity.tableName} RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;`,
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score -3):

You may not have to purge the database for this test.  You could alternatively use a library like [faker](https://github.com/Marak/Faker.js) and bypass the email duplicate validation.  Faker will produce a unique user with every test run.  Change your user to:

```
import fake from 'faker';

const user: IStringTMap<string> = {
  firstName: faker.name.firstName(),
  lastName: faker.name.lastName(),
  email: faker.internet.email(),
  password: faker.internet.password()
}
```